# How would the MUL operation on AX with Pi (3,1415..) in (8.8) format work in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, fixed-point

Im new to Assembly and am learning Fix-point arithmetic.

AX is a 16-Bit register-

```
 MUL Pi  ; Multiplies EAX with Pi and stores result in EAX
 DIV 256 ; Divides EAX by 256 which equals the necessary right- shift for the 8,8 format
```

But I dont think it works like this.

Comment: Multiplying two 16-bit values gives you a 32-bit value, and then for 8,8 you have to divide the 32-bit value by 256 and stuff it back into a 16-bit register (presumably), which is the same as taking the middle 2 bytes (you don't have to actually do a division!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `MUL` instruction with a word sized operand multiplies `AX` with that operand and places its result in `DX:AX`.  If both operands are in 8.8 format, the result will be in 16.16 format with the integral part in `DX` and the fractional part in `AX`.  To convert this to 8.8 format, you take the contents of `DL` and `AH` like this:

```
MUL Pi        ; multiple by Pi, leaving the integral part in DX and the fraction in AX
MOV AL, AH    ; move the fractional part into place
MOV AH, DL    ; move the integral part into place
```

And everything should work out just fine.  Note that the rounding might be off a little.  You can correct for that like this:

```
MUL Pi        ; multiple by Pi, leaving the integral part in DX and the fraction in AX
ADD AX, 0080h ; apply rounding to AH
ADC DX, 0     ; apply carry if any
MOV AL, AH    ; move the fractional part into place
MOV AH, DL    ; move the integral part into place
```

This rounds the result correctly according to the principle

```
round(x) = ⌊x + 0.5⌋
```

Comment: thank you! When multiplying two 16 Bit Registers or Register/Value the Result is stored in the EAX- register. So atm. I dont understand why the integer part is in DX and the fraction in AX. And also: why in AH in AX, DL in DX.

Comment: @user14585966 Are you doing a word or a dword multiplication?  How is `Pi` defined?

Comment: its represented in 16 bit so word

Comment: @user14585966: No, `mul word [Pi]` does `DX:AX = AX * [Pi]`, not EAX, even if the machine is 32-bit capable.  Read the manual https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul.  If you could assume 386 (for registers like EAX), you could also use instructions like `shrd AX, DX, 8` to shift the 32-bit product right by 8 bits, leaving the middle 16 bits of it in AX.   Or you could zero- or sign-extend your inputs and use 32-bit `imul`